# caching not working for map

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Java - Spring - ehcache

have following code to implement eh-cache working perfect for list of objects but when i tried to cache maps it always trying to load fresh copy... does cache does not work for map ? any help appreciated.

Spring configuration

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    cmfb.setShared(true);
    return cmfb;
}


<!-- ehcache entry -->
    <cache name="serviceMapCache" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="50000" 
        eternal="false" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToLiveSeconds="10800" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
```

Usage

```
@Cacheable(value=CacheNames.SERVICE_MAP_CACHE)
public Map<String, Service> getAllServicesToMap(){
 // load map 
 // return map
 }
```

Comment: I thin what I would do in this case is inserting all element one by one " since cache is key-value set" then there is a Map<Object, Element> getAll(Collection<?> keys) API present which returns you the map of keys to values corresponding to the keys you pass in the method.
And there is List getKeys() method too exposed which will return u all the keys present in the cache. Using these two methods i think you can get all elements in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to use a disk store, you need to make sure the object you cache are `Serializable`.
In the case of your map example, it means the map itself, the keys and the values it contains.